# Unable to send email from Python due to Address Family not supported Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am geeting an error while I am trying to send an automated email from python.

The error I am getting is "[Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol"

```
# import necessary packages
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "password"
msg['From'] = "risk@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "game@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Photos"

# attach image to message body


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

How can I fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change this line: `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')`

Comment: @DroidX86, changed to server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587') . Still same failing due to same error

Comment: Try `SMTP_SSL` instead

Comment: @DroidX86, same error

Comment: Are the host and port meant to be a single string? Does it help changing that to smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)? That seems to be the signature at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/smtplib.html.

Comment: I'm auditing my old answers.  I was wondering did this answer help you with your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if you have resolved this problem, so I'm posting the code that worked for me.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "password"
msg['From'] = "risk@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "game@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Photos"

text = "Here are the photos.\nCheers,\nLife is complex"
msg_text = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
msg.attach (msg_text)

fp = open('image.png', 'rb')
img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg.attach(img)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

> BTW have you enabled the Gmail security setting that allows "less
>   secure application access' to your Gmail account? This setting allows
>   your python script to interact with your account.

[image: Gmail Security Setting]